# Как узнать, какой из Deferred вернул ошибку при использовании awaitAll?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx-coroutines

Есть ли способ узнать, какой из Deferred-ов вернул ошибку при использовании awaitAll?

Согласно [документации awaitAll](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/await-all.html),

> Awaits for completion of given deferred values without blocking a thread and resumes normally with the list of values when all deferred computations are complete or resumes with the first thrown exception if any of computations complete exceptionally including cancellation.

Не хочется терять преимущество использования awaitAll перед
`deferreds.map { it.await() }`, но может быть можно понять, какой именно deferred завершился с ошибкой?

Comment: Что значит узнать какой deferred? В каком виде данные должны быть и как вы их собираетесь использовать?